# Create new Schema in Postgres when new user register, using Prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, multi-tenant, prisma

I am working on an application in which every user has their own schema (Postgres schema). I am using postages, nestJs, and Prisma Orm.
I have developed a schema-based multi-tenant, that works fine but I have to generate a Prisma client every time when new (Postgres) schema required. I want to create a new (Postgres) schema or database when a new user registers.

**In conclusion, I want to create a (Postgres) schema dynamically (Programmatically).**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to create schema programmatically.

Consider this function for creating schema if the schema doesn't exist.

You can invoke this function any time you need to create a new schema.

```js
import { PrismaClient, User } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {
  // ... you will write your Prisma Client queries here
  const result = await prisma.$executeRaw`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS prisma`;

  console.log('result', result);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to copy of schema with all tables, like prisma migrate deploy, with new url